# How do I use one binding for multiple text boxes to separate three-digit numbers in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use C# WPF in Visual Studio 2019

I want to display my TextBoxes values as Thousands decimal separated like this `1500.9 => 1,500.9`

I Choose **Validation Rules and Binding** for this problem because I don't want to use C# Code Behind and Another point is that this option alone does nothing for a text box

```
 StringFormat="0,0.0"
```

**What is My Problem** :

I thought Binding in Validation Rule uses this type of property for formatting ,
I did bind all of my textboxes to my property and now all text boxes have the same value even when I change one of them
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CVd1.png)

**My Project** :

here is my Model name as  `Validator.cs` :

```
namespace WpfApp5
{
    public class Validator
    {
        public double dbl_numeric { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My window for binding textboxes :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.Budget_Default"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
          
           xmlns:validate="clr-namespace:WpfApp5.Validation"
             
        AllowDrop="True"
        Height="550" Width="1033" >
    <Grid x:Name="mygrid">   
                 
         <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"  >
            <Binding Path = "dbl_numeric" UpdateSourceTrigger = "PropertyChanged" StringFormat="0,0.0">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = "True"/>
                    <validate:RequeredViladation/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox>
        
         <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2"  >
            <Binding Path = "dbl_numeric" UpdateSourceTrigger = "PropertyChanged" StringFormat="0,0.0">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = "True"/>
                    <validate:RequeredViladation/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox>
        
          <TextBox x:Name="TextBox3"  >
            <Binding Path = "dbl_numeric" UpdateSourceTrigger = "PropertyChanged" StringFormat="0,0.0">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = "True"/>
                    <validate:RequeredViladation/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

**What I need** :

How to use Validation Rule or something to Display Thousands of Separated decimal numbers to use strings format for my textboxes

long story short : Each textbox should be separated into 3 digits, 3 digits for its own value only

**1500.9 => 1,500.9**

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to format the value bound to the textbox, this would suffice:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=dbl_numeric,StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
```

This will give you a culture specific separator for thousands, and two decimal places.

Validation is another topic. Note that out of the box, WPF will check if a value can be parsed as a double, and put a red border around a textbox if, for example, you input text. You may want to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus` if you want to allow a user to type in a complete value before validating. If you have other validation needs, you will have to manually add this.

You three text boxes are currently all bound to the same value in the model (which typically would be a view model in WPF).

Comment: thanks for your answer , so What can I do if only 3 digits separate 3 digits but the values are not the same? I don't want they I do not want them all to have the same value

Comment: Is there a way to format only one text box string? Without binding

Comment: I think it will be harder to achieve the formatting without binding; fact is, WPF has been designed for this to function best with bindings. To begin with, WPF has been designed to use bindings between your (view)model and the view.
I'm unsure about your first comment; you can simply declare three properties on your (view)model and bind each of them to a separate TextBox.

Comment: Thanks , I did what you sad , but now I when I typing a number the Selection Start does not work correctly

Comment: What do you mean by selection start?

Comment: Try my code you will find it , you can't type easily number when UpdateSourceTrigger = "PropertyChanged" is true because you have to use mouse to change decimal number In fact, you can not type numbers in the keyboard with the keyboard because the order of the numbers is broken.

Comment: I can't type point in the textbox like 1,500.9  it will be 1,500 or 1,500.9.9

Comment: Like I mentioned, you may want to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus`, cause otherwise WPF will validate the input value even before the user is able to type in a complete double with a decimal separator.